# Error message when compiling while-loop expected identifier

Tags: xcode, while-loop

When trying to compile an infinite while loop in xcode iphone view based application, it gives me an error that reads expected identifier or '(' before 'while'.  I made it as simple as possible.  Sorry about the picture.  Code block was not working.  If you want to see an image of the code, here is the link.  http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/931d5d8788.gif

```
#import "Lockerz_NotifierViewController.h"

@implementation Lockerz_NotifierViewController
NSMutableData *responseData;

while (1) {
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://amicionline.me"]
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                            timeoutInterval:60.0];
    // create a connection
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if(theConnection) {
        // create the datum
        responseData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
    } else {
        // code this later
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // make it work
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data:",[responseData length]);

    // release it
    [connection release];
    [responseData release];

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}
```

Comment: this is the whole file ?

Comment: Yes, please post the whole file. This code will never compile, but as for the while loop specifically, you can't assign to constants, so 1=1 is not valid in C. For infinite loops you can do either while(1) or for(;;).

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? You can't write code directly in an `@implementation`. You must put it inside a method, for example:

```
-(void)start {
   while (1) {
     ...
   }
}
```